# GTK : How to set the Height of a VBox?

Tags: c++, linux, gtk, gtkmm

Hi I'm making an app using GTKMM. The screenshot is below:

[Screenshot](http://img17.yfrog.com/i/captureohu.jpg/)

The Problem is, I'm not able to position the "My Label" to align at the top, just below the Search box.

I'm packing Name,Search box, Search Button into a HBox, which is packed into a VBox, and then MyLabel is packed into the VBox.

I think the problem is that the VBox is assigning equal heights to the two rows, So even though I align MYLabel to the top, but it's top is the middle of the screen 'cuz VBox distributed the heights between the two rows equally.

Is there a way to set the Heights of the VBox rows?? or any other way out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the `"expand"` and `"fill"` properties of the label to `false`.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked.

For anyone facing similar problem, I solved the problem using the advice below, set the expand and fill property to false in my call to VBox pack_start(Widget& child,false,false) function.